# Bootstrap: Can't add background color to a grid row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to Bootstrap. I'm working on a very simple website. However, I'm having trouble adding a background-color property to a my rows. I was hoping someone could help me figure out where I'm going wrong

Here's my HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
         content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Pizza Store</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                    <h1>Pizza Store</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="containter">
        <div< class="row menu-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h3>Vegetable Pizza</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                A Pizza with Vegetables on it
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div< class="row menu-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h3>Cheese Pizza</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                A Pizza with only cheese
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the mystyle.css file

```
.row-header{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px auto;
}

.menu-content {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px ridge;
    min-height:400px;
    background-color: #76A0D3;
}

.row-footer{
    background-color: #AfAfAf;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding:70px 30px 70px 30px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}


address{
    font-size:80%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#0f0f0f;
}

hr {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 8px auto;
   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   border: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

All classes are working fine except the menu-content class style. In that class, the only thing that's not working is the background-color property. Could someone please explain why that is?

Thanks for the help

Comment: `.menu-content` background works, but you don't have a `.row-footer` in your markup. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWmOqW what's the problem?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Also what I was thinking.

Comment: @MichaelCoker - That's strange. For some reason, it's not applying the background color when I run it. Also, regarding the footer, I'll be adding that in later. I'm still working on the webpage. Edit: It did work however, after I put each or the rows inside of div tags with class="menu-content" Is that how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: Check that all of your CSS files are linked correctly and applied on your HTML page. There are also some code errors I have noticed, e.g. there is a `<div class="containter">` in there and also `<div< class="row menu-content">`. Finally, try including `div.menu-content` instead of `.menu-content` in your CSS file.

Comment: @dat3450 - Thank You. It turns out that it was the typos. I'm sorry for wasting your time. Still trying to get used to keeping track of everything.